# Possible memory leak from a handled exception? (With exception handling that calls exit().)

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm working on a C++ application (an OpenSSL assignment for university), and I'm running it through valgrind, as one does. I've noticed some rather strange output when the program fails due to invalid input:

```
==1739== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1739==     in use at exit: 588 bytes in 6 blocks
==1739==   total heap usage: 52 allocs, 46 frees, 99,206 bytes allocated
==1739== 
==1739== 44 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 6
==1739==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1739==    by 0x4C20378: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1739==    by 0x4C03187: std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1739==    by 0x4C0325C: std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1739==    by 0x10FB6D: lab2::cryptoEngine::CBCCryptoEngine::encrypt() (CBCCryptoEngine.cpp:39)
==1739==    by 0x10E355: main (main.cpp:135)
==1739== 
==1739== 144 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 6
==1739==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1739==    by 0x4BDB1F3: __cxa_allocate_exception (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==1739==    by 0x10FB5B: lab2::cryptoEngine::CBCCryptoEngine::encrypt() (CBCCryptoEngine.cpp:39)
==1739==    by 0x10E355: main (main.cpp:135)
==1739== 
==1739== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1739==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1739==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1739==      possibly lost: 188 bytes in 2 blocks
==1739==    still reachable: 400 bytes in 4 blocks
==1739==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==1739==                         stdstring          : 44 bytes in 1 blocks
==1739==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1739== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==1739== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==1739== 
==1739== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
```

The code causing it is just a regular exception that is thrown when an input file is invalid. The exception is caught properly like this:

```cpp
try {
    engine.encrypt(bad_argument); // Placeholder. The exception type stands, though...
}
catch (const std::invalid_argument &e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception while encrypting file: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    delete (engine);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what it means, and if it is even a problem, since the memory will be reclaimed by the OS anyway. But I've never seen this kind of thing before, and wanted to check.

So, my question is, what is it caused by? Should I fix it? If so, how?

Comment: I'd look at `CBCCryptoEngine.cpp:39`. How does it throw the exception? Is the `char const*` it supplies a temporary?

Comment: Which version of Valgrind is this? Which platform?

Comment: @TedLyngmo - It’s a string literal. The full line is `throw std::invalid_argument(“Input file is invalid”);`

Comment: @PaulFloyd - It’s 3.16.1 (I believe) on Debian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::logic_error`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) allocated memory for the "explanatory string". This is `what()` returns to you, in the exception handler (`std::invalid_argument` inherits from `std::logic_error`).

Observe that the backtrace shows the constructor overload that takes a `const char *` for a parameter. It would've been acceptable if that literal `const char *` got stashed away, and handed back to you from `what()`. However there are various immaterial reasons why the constructor is coded to make a copy of the "explanatory string" so that its contents are wholly owned by the constructed `std::logic_error`.

Your exception handler quietly called `exit()` and the process terminated. At which point `valgrind` notified you that the aforementioned allocated memory wasn't destroyed. This is true, that memory wasn't deallocated.

Had your exception handler's scope ended naturally (without calling `exit()`), `std::logic_error`'s destructor would've deleted the allocated memory, and everyone would've lived happily ever after.

TLDR: this is only a technical memory leak. It is technically true only because the rug was pulled from under the process, by calling `exit`.

Note that `valgrind` said "possibly" instead of "definitely". There's no doubt that you have a memory leak when valgrind "definitely" claims one. If it's just "possibly", then there may or may not be a real memory leak.

Comment: You can translate "possibly" to mean "definitely unless you use a sub-allocating memory manager or a technique like Pascal style length:data strings".

Answer (score 5):

`exit` loses more or less everything not recursively owned by objects of static storage duration. Of course this includes everything recursively owned by things on the stack, but also the active exception object (its memory is allocated in an unspecified way). In this particular case, you lose a buffer owned by a `std::string` owned by the active exception object.

If you care about such things, don't use `exit` in the middle of things. Rethrow the exception, catch it in `main`, let the handler finish, and *then* call `exit` (or just fall out of `main` naturally). You probably shouldn't, as this is not a real leak (i.e. there is no memory allocated and lost by the program *while it is still running*).

Comment: Agreed. Most code has bigger fish to fry than leaks related to exceptions.